# How to Dynamically Size Crispy Form in Django

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I have a form that is appearing as 1 line. I'd like for the size of the window to expand dynamically depending on how much text is entered:
[image]

Here is the html info from the page it is in:

`home.html`

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
          <form action="" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form2|crispy }}<br>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Paste" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
          </form>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
```

`forms.py`

```
from django import forms
from pastes.models import Paste

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    SYNTAX_CHOICES = {
        (0, "Plain"),
        (1, "Python"),
        (2, "HTML"),
        (3, "SQL"),
        (4, "Javascript"),
        (5, "CSS"),
    }

    class Meta:
        model       = Paste
        fields      = ('title', 'content', 'syntax', 'public')
        widgets = {"title": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"})}
```

Comment: mind sharing your `forms.py`?

Comment: @Walucas I've edited my OP

Comment: Is content a TextField or CharField?

Comment: @Walucas It is a CharField. It would be better to switch to TextField, no?

Comment: Really depends on what you are storing. You can always render a charfield AS a textfield on the form, but it would not hold as much info. Let me know, I can give you an example in a proper answer

Comment: It would be pastes of things, similar to what you would put into Pastebin.

Comment: Oh, so I think you really want a textfield